# Know which node.js version a framework depends on

Tags: node.js, angular, karma-runner

I'm using karma test runner, version 1.7.1. I want to know if there is a away to know what is the minimum node version the framework karma needs to run.

As a bonus, I want to know if there is a away to know the node version dependency for any framework that I'm using on my project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`package.json` contains a lot of metadata like this!

You can look in the `engines.node` field. Many libraries will include the required version of node - [in the case of Karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/package.json) that's any Node.js version `>= 6`.

Comment: Although it looks like back in `1.7.1` it was set to `0.10 || 0.12 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8`

Answer (score 0):

Package authors most of the time specify required node version in `package.json`

Take a look at [karma's](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/karma/package.json)

Myself I'm looking for info like this on [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/). 
In the package details sidebar there is link to package.json

[image: usage group]